# single element string array to boolean

Tags: groovy

I have

```
String test = "[true]"
```

How can I check if this can be a boolean element?  Is there a clean way to do this or do I need to create a function to trim off the sides and check the type?

Comment: `test.toLowerCase().contains("true") || test.toLowerCase().contains("false")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own function for that

```
public boolean convertToBoolean(String input) throws Exception{
    if(input == null){
        throw new Exception("Input is null");
    }
    if(input.toLowerCase().contains("true")){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I was looking for.  Wouldn't have thought to check for nulls

Answer (score 1):

Trim of the brackets and then use the `Boolean(String s)` constructor to creat a new boolean

```
String sb = "[true]";
Boolean b = new Boolean(sb.substring(1, sb.length()-1));
```

Now you can use this boolean in your if statement:

```
    if(b)
        System.out.println(true);
    else
        System.out.println(false);
```